# PageFactory seems to be slow when used in Appium iOS automation

Tags: appium-ios, page-factory

We are automating a react-native iOS app using Appium. We are using PageFactory design pattern. For clicking a element, this is the code am using:

1. Waiting for element to be visible.
2. Clicking on the element

```js
public  Boolean waitUntilVisible(WebElement element)
{
 try {
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
  return true;
 }catch (Exception e)
 {}
 return false;
}

public boolean click(WebElement element)
{
 //Click on the element and return true if successful and false if unsuccessful.
 try 
 {
        waitUntilVisible(element);
  element.click();
 } catch (Exception e) {}
 return false;
}
```

The overall execution seems to be taking too much time. As per my understanding, waitUntilVisible waits until the element's isDisplayed() became true.
As we are using PageFactory, I assume that element identification occurs twice.
1. The element will be identified first before checking for visibility.
2. The same element will be identified again before click.

Since we are using xpath in many areas, the element identification usually takes longer time. For a simple click, the same element is identified twice which further increases the time.

I want to know any solution to store the identified element so that it won't spend time in identifying it again.

So I modified my code like below:

```js
public  WebElement waitUntilVisible(WebElement element)
{
 try {
  return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
 }catch (Exception e)
 {}
 return null;
}

public boolean click(WebElement element)
{
 //Click on the element and return true if successful and false if unsuccessful.
 try 
 {
        WebElement remoteElement = waitUntilVisible(element);
  remoteElement.click();
 } catch (Exception e) {}
 return false;
}
```

> This method doesn't seem to save time.

Is there any other way for me to reduce the execution time.

Note: We are using WebElement instead of IOSElement so that the same code which was used in Desktop automation can be used in IOS Automation as well.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mobileElement = driver.findElement(MobileBy.locator("locator"));
appiumDriverActions.moveToElement(mobileElement).click().perform();
appiumWait.until(ExpectedConditions.condition(Element/locator));
```

instead of

```
mobileElement = driver.findElement(MobileBy.locator("locator"));
mobileElement.click();
```

in some cases with the new default VC from iOS13, it is better to moveToElement then use action click instead of `element.click();`

for more details, https://medium.com/@ayman.ibrahim.mansour/appiums-best-way-to-deal-with-the-new-view-controller-presentation-in-ios-13-6d801fcc3cb

Comment: My question is not regarding the problem in using action click. Its about the comparison between usage of PageFactory and By variables.

Comment: this is the point, what really consumes the most of the time is not pageFactory behavior, it is the click command behavior. actually the pageFactory behavior is preferable to keep the TC passing and Avoid having Elements Stale

Comment: in this method `public boolean click(WebElement element)` instead of using `element.click();` try to use `actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();`  this should make your automation faster, in case of iOS 13 and higher. 
the change you did only replace the pageFactory with the pure selenium, which will not cause a reduction in the time since pageFactory anyway don't consume that much time, what consumes time is the `element.click()` itself